# Have a path point to the middle of another path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Using Javascript, given the Bezier curve string of an SVG path, is there a simple way to obtain the midpoint of that path?

I want to have a path point to the middle of the first path, but all I have is the string in `<path d="...">`. I'd rather not have to parse the string and manually calculate the midpoint of the Bezier curve if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but if you get hold of the `<path>` node in JS, it will be an [`SVGPathElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement) and thus you might be able to use:

```
var len = path.getTotalLength();
var midPoint = path.getPointAtLength(len/2);
```